# Filling Dropdowns From Web-Service SOAP Response

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Using PHP, I am working to create a series of dropdown menus that work in a sequential order while populating via numerous web-service calls.

For example, a user will select a year from dropdown #1. With that year, I then make a SOAP call (using only the given year) to gather makes and populate dropdown #2. This will then make another SOAP call (using the given year and make) to gather models. This will then make another SOAP call (using the given year, make, and model) to gather an id. A final SOAP call will then be made using the given ID to get the desired data.

My question, how can I go about accomplishing this with so many calls and "holding" all the needed values throughout the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of options on how to architect this page, but I would recommend using using AJAX requests with Javascript.  On the first drop-down selection, an AJAX request is triggered, which calls a PHP script, SOAP call is completed, response converted to JSON, which is used to populate the next drop-down.  Rinse and repeat for subsequent drop-downs.

Using this method you can take advantage of caching the SOAP results, so common responses are re-used, and your app is fast.

Use the popular [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library to accomplish your AJAX requests and drop-down population.

Comment: This is exactly the route I went, thanks providing the clarification of the process and leading me in the right direction.